# How to hover over the whole button in css

Tags: css

When I hover over the whole button, I would like it to appear over the whole button. Because the button has a background image, i am not able to do it correctly. The buttons looks like these:

[image]

The CSS appears like this:

```
#tablist{
  padding: 0px auto 0px auto;
  height: 32px;
}

#tablist li{
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px; 
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    cursor: hand; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

#tablist ul:hover{
 background-color: red;
}

.tablink{
  text-decoration:none;
}

.locked{
    background: url('../img/DashboardButtonsLocked.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:5px -85px;
}
.unlocked{
    background: url('../img/DashboardButtonsLocked.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:4px -2px;
}
```

How do i correct it? Need some guidance over it.

Comment: wht exactly do you want lakesh....

Comment: Add a jsFiddle to demo the problem. I have no idea what you need help with.

Comment: the problem  was the image was blocking the hovering to occur. @gabitzish answer solved it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the background property at hover:

```
#tablist ul:hover{
   background: red;
}
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/taQfU/

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think you should give to `#tablist li:hover`

As like this

```
#tablist li:hover{
 background-color: red;
}
```